# How to remove a comment in Google Translator Toolkit?

Tags: google, google-translate

I am trying to find a way to remove my comments from documents opened with [Google Translator Toolkit](http://translate.google.com/toolkit).

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Whoa! Thanks for showing a Google service I've never known!

Comment: @dnbrv It is recent and Google added just in these days new features for Android developers; could be that some features have not been implemented yet or have some bugs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the comment can open the comment box that needs to be deleted and simply delete the text inside it, then click the X on the upper right to make the comment box disappear.